# Javascript regex placeholder prints string instead of its value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript function which looks for a string of certain format and then converts it into a link

```js
<script>
var re = /Ticket-([0-9]*?(?=-)-[0-9]*)/; 
var str = 'ASD Ticket-492-367 - Make my day.'; 
t = str.replace(re,'<a href="http://myworld/ticket/$1">$0</a>')
document.write(t);
</script>
```

It looks for Ticket-[some numbers]-[somenumbers] and converts it into a link. Now when i run it seperately in JS editors online it works. But when I run it in my script and lok at the page it does convert the string into a list but prints out literal $0 on the page instead of its value. Is my Javascript correct or ist something else in my script that's probably cuasing the erraneous relsuts. As always, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript uses `$&` as the placeholder for the entire match, not `$0` `$number` is only used as the placeholder for capture groups in parentheses. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Description).

```js
var re = /Ticket-([0-9]*?(?=-)-[0-9]*)/; 
var str = 'ASD Ticket-492-367 - Make my day.'; 
t = str.replace(re,'<a href="http://myworld/ticket/$1">$&</a>')
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = t;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: But it works in the cas eof $1. Why? How do you differentiate between matched groups

Comment: `$number` is for capture groups in parentheses. `$&` is for the match of the whole regexp.

Comment: just as a helpful note, http://regexr.com/ has a fantastic reference section on the left side of the page. 
If you go to Reference -> Substitution, it will give you the differences and examples between the operators in real time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're matching a list you should use /g to make the regex global. $0 doesn't grab the matched value, $& does.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2p91co2g/

EDIT: Apparently jsfiddle is down or something. The HTML I used was:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Ticket-445-1235 - Make my day<br>
Ticket-445-1255 - Make his day<br>
Ticket-443-4356 - He's feeling lucky<br>
Ticket-443-5555 - punk<br>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript with the adjustments are:

```
window.onload = function() {
var re = /Ticket-([0-9]*?(?=-)-[0-9]*)/g; 
var str = document.body.innerHTML; 
t = str.replace(re,'<a href="http://myworld/ticket/$1">$&</a>')
document.write(t);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try escaping the dollar twice...

```
\\$
```

Comment: That will just put a literal backslash in the replacement.